# Pass Values from Popup VC to controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently in my App I am opening a popup View Controller inside a normal View Controller, and need to pass values back from my Popup VC to the normal VC.

This is how I am making the popups.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IconEditPopup") as! IconEditPopup
    // this is where you can set values in the view
    vc.id = "12"
    self.addChild(vc)
    vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Basically just want to pass values back from the popup View controller to my normal VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Delegate` pattern or `Clouser` callback handler to pass a value back to the parent view.

here is a example:

Define a clouser in your popVC like this:

```
var clouserName: ((returnType) -> Void)?
```

Inside your popVC where you need to call the clouser:

```
clouserName?(returnValue)
```

in your parent controller, capture the value in this way:

```
vc.clouserName = { returnValue in // dont forget [weak self] if you need self
 // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Does the vc.clouseraName { returnValue in.    Run when the value is passed?

Comment: Yes, when you call it in popVC, it's triggered in parent vc

Comment: you can put it where you define your popVC, it's ok in viewDidLoad too

Comment: Thank you so much!